# using require() in karma tests

Tags: requirejs, karma-runner

I'm using Karma 0.12.28, Karma-Requirejs 0.2.2 (and Karam-jasmine) to run tests.
Config is almost identical to one from docs (test files in requirejs deps and `window.__ karma __.start` as callback).
Everything works just fine for basic tests. The problem starts when I use `require()` instead of `define()` or try to change context. Basically something like this:

```
var ctx = require.config({
  context: 'my-context'
});
ctx(['dep1'], function(){
  //....
});
```

The problem is dep1 fails to load. In DevTools I can see `<script/>` is created and I can see request in network tab with proper URL but status is canceled. I can open this URL using context menu so I'm sure it is correct but the question remains - **why can't I use `require()` in karma tests?**